# Не получается перебрать коллекцию в JS

Tags: javascript

Выполняю поиск через `getElementByTagName('div')`
после чего пытаюсь перебрать с помощью `forEach` и добавить `padding`, но выдает ошибку.

В чем проблема, как правильно перебирать ?

```js
'use strict'

let allDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
console.log(allDiv)

allDiv.forEach(element => {
  element.setAttribute('style', 'padding: 10px;')
});
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: "но выдает ошибку." --- надо догадаться какую?)

Comment: Просто замените на `document.querySelectorAll('div')`. У коллекции, возвращаемой `getElementsByTagName()` нет метода `forEach`. Ну или `[...document.getElementsByTagName('div')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*JavaScript* имеет несколько типов коллекций (`HTMLCollection`, `NodeList`, `FileList`, `'arguments'` и пр.).
`getElementsByTagName` возвращает живую коллекцию элементов `HTMLCollection`. У коллекции данного типа нет метода `forEach`.
Поэтому надо принудительно перевести в массив например через `Array.from`

Метод `Array.from()` создаёт новый экземпляр `Array` из массивоподобного или итерируемого объекта, коим является `HTMLCollection`

```js
let allDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')


Array.from(allDiv).forEach(element => {
  element.setAttribute('style', 'padding: 10px;')
});
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: _надо принудительно перевести в массив_ - либо воспользоваться обычным `for`

Comment: ............Yes